# Decryption issue with private key and passphrase

Tags: python, python-2.7, public-key-encryption, gnupg, private-key

can you people please help with below problem.

I am new t encryption and decryption things in python.

I was provided both pgp private.key and public.key files to do a simple encryption and decryption on a text file.

```
import gnupg as g
import os
from datetime import datetime

#Home directory
gpg = g.GPG('/key/')
date1 =datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')
file1_combined_faia_csv='test_file.txt'
file1_combined_faia='test_encry.pgp'
key_data = None

print 'pen the public key file.'

with open('priv.key','rb') as f:
    Key_data = f.read()

print 'Importing Key data from the keydata'

key = gpg.import_keys(Key_data)

#List the Keys from the data 

pub_key = gpg.list_keys()

key_data = pub_key[2]

with open(file1_combined_faia_csv,'rb') as file:
    file_data= file.read()

data = gpg.encrypt(file_data,key_data["keyid"])

with open(file1_combined_faia,'w+') as dec:
    dec.write(str(data))

print 'for PIC Encryption done!!!'

print 'OK: ' + str(data.ok)
print 'Msg: ' + str(data.status)
print 'Error: ' + str(data.stderr)
```

Blow is my original string.

```
Hi this is tharun from data team.
```

And it encrypted successfully.
Please look below of my decryption code. I was provided passphrase also by my client.

```
import gnupg as g
import os
from datetime import datetime

#Home directory
gpg = g.GPG('/key/')
date1 =datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')
file1_combined_faia_csv='test_encry.pgp'
file1_combined_faia='test_decryped.txt'
key_data = None

print 'pen the private key file.'

with open('priv.key','rb') as f:
    Key_data = f.read()

key = gpg.import_keys(Key_data)

pub_key = gpg.list_keys(True)
key_data = pub_key[0]

file_data = None


print 'for FAIA Encrypting.........'
with open(file1_combined_faia_csv,'rb') as file:
    file_data= file.read()


data = gpg.decrypt(str(file_data),passphrase="*************"
with open(file1_combined_faia,'w+') as dec:
    dec.write(str(data))

print 'for PIC Decryption done!!!'

print 'OK: ' + str(data.ok)
print 'Msg: ' + str(data.status)
print 'Error: ' + str(data.stderr)
```

Below is the error message

```
[GNUPG:] NO_SECKEY D43DA661974C8582
[GNUPG:] BEGIN_DECRYPTION
[GNUPG:] DECRYPTION_FAILED
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
[GNUPG:] END_DECRYPTION
```

I am doing above things based on some sample tutorials. I think i am missng some thing while decrypting. I may use both private key and passphrase but not sure how.

can you please help me on the decryption part.

Please let me know if any further info needed.

Thanks

Comment: You seem to have a lot of superfluous code in your script. Have a look at the example [here](https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2011/10/python-gnupg-gpg-example/). If you are not able to recreate this you may have a deeper issue in your settings.